# From extension method to lambda with receiver, how?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, extension-methods

```kotlin
class SomeClass{
  val logger = ...
  fun (String).capitalizeLast():String {
    logger.info("capitalizeLast called")
    return this.substring(0,this.length-1) + this.substring(this.length-1,this.length).toUpperCase()
  }
  val asLambda: (String).()->String = <<dark magic using the previously defined extension method??
}
```

I mean, I could always write

```kotlin
val asLambda: (String).()->String = {
  this.capitalizeLast()
}
```

But is there not a syntactic sugar using `::` (as with `::println`)

Comment: You want to capitalize the last letter of a string and keep others intact. Right?

Answer (score 3):

There's a shorter way to capitalize the last character. You can do:

```
str.dropLast(1) + str.last().uppercase()
```

You can make a extension function out of it:

```kotlin
fun String.capitalizeLast() = dropLast(1) + last().uppercase()
```

Usage:

```kotlin
println("hello".capitalizeLast())
```

And you can refer to this function using `String::capitalizeLast`. Example:

```kotlin
val strings = listOf("hello", "world")
strings.map(String::capitalizeLast)
```

[try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/YK6JCSyVX)

**Edit:** From your comment below, it seems to me that you want to capture a function, which has an argument as well as a receiver, in a variable. Take a look at the following example:

```kotlin
fun Int.addLongGiveDouble(num: Long): Double {
    return (this + num).toDouble()
}

fun main() {
    val lambda: Int.(Long) -> Double = Int::addLongGiveDouble
    val result: Double = 5.lambda(10L) // result is 15.0
}
```

Comment: I think I ruined the question. My real question, and I see I failed to convey it, was about using that syntax for methods with receiver AND parameters. `(SomeType).someMethod(someParam:SomeParam) ===> (SomeType).(SomeParam)->Unit` ... it seems that syntax doesn't work there

Comment: I have edited my answer based on what I understood from your comment. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I get an error "someMethod is a member and an extension at the same time. Reference to such elements are not allowed". I think the problem is that my extension method is defined inside a class, and that doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the exact code that you are trying? You can add it to the question itself.

Comment: Done @Arpit Shukla

Comment: [This](https://pl.kotl.in/Xp4NR2Mhk) works for me. Are you doing something different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239558/discussion-between-alejandro-navas-and-arpit-shukla).

Answer (score 2):

Lambda is the wrong terminology here. Lambda is just a syntax alternative for a functional object. A functional object is not a lambda. You're trying to get a functional object out of the extension function.

It's the same for extension functions as for member functions:

```
val asFunctionObject: String.()->String = String::capitalizeLast
```

Note that `String.() -> String` and `(String) -> String` are effectively the same type. The distinction only matters when it's used as the type of a function parameter and affects how lambdas are parsed when lambda syntax is used with a higher-order function.